# Scheme Runtime Symbol Dereference

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme

Are there any cases in Scheme when one would need to be able to dereference a symbol (in R7RS-small, if it matters) at runtime? I'm looking into writing a compiler and, if runtime symbol dereferencing isn't necessary, then I will do it at compile time since that's easier and probably way more efficient.

To give an example:

```
(define (fac n) 
  (if (> n 1) 
    (* n (f (- n 1)))
    1))

; When I compile this, I know from the last line what fac is and can compile this as a direct call to my compiled function, fac.
(fac 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
(define (fac n) 
  (if (> n 1) 
    (* n (fac (- n 1)))
    1))

(fac 5) ;-> 120

(define fac2 fac)
(set! fac (lambda a 10))

(fac2 5) ;-> 50
```

All variables are mutable, and the reference to the name `fac` inside the function body continues to look up the definition from the global scope every time the function is run, meaning that the behaviour of the function can change at any time if it contains a reference to a global variable, even though none of its body code changes.

If you want to be able to optimize things down to direct calls to static targets, you need to make sure they only search within a known closed scope (one that doesn't export any procedures that might modify that variable themselves). e.g.:

```
(define fac 
    (letrec ((fac (lambda (n)    
                     (if (> n 1) (* n (fac (- n 1))) 1) )))
      fac) )

(fac 5) ;-> 120
(define fac2 fac)
(set! fac (lambda a 10))                                   
(fac2 5) ;-> 120
```

This definition of `fac` has the body searching within the scope established by `letrec`, which you can statically prove is never modified and therefore can be compiled to a simple static call.

You can write definitions of multiple functions, depending on each other and other names from the global toplevel, within e.g. the same `let` block, to provide a closed context that lets them use more efficient lookup internally. The [Chez Scheme documentation explicitly recommends doing this](http://www.scheme.com/csug7/use.html#./use:h4) to make life easier for its optimizer.

Comment: This might not be a problem is he intends to compile like Stalin (virgin Scheme, load, execute, exit)

Comment: It took me a while to see the problem. And it *is* a problem. So runtime symbol management is necessary? At this point, isn't it almost pointless to compile, if every reference to a variable has to go through a runtime library, is there any benefit to compilation over interpretation?

Comment: @Tyler *variable* management is necessary... you might want to clarify in the q. exactly what you mean by "symbol" management (Scheme doesn't have dynamic symbol lookup like some Lisps). The above only affects mutable variables at the top-level and in other contexts where the compiler can't prove they are never modified - anything you can permanently capture in a local scope or module provides plenty of opportunity for optimization. Properly capturing e.g. arithmetic operators can often let a good compiler produce very fast code.